# Bounding boxes not showing for FasterRcnn model

Tags: python, opencv, keras, deep-learning

Am trying to draw bounding boxes around the person who shows up on screen. But it seems like, the code has detected the person in frame but unable to draw bounding boxes to it. 
Please help me fixing this issue.
 Am using this model, **faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco_2018_01_28** 

**Source Code**

```
def draw_boxes(result,imgToDisplay,w,h):

    #Draw bounding boxes onto the frame.
    for box in result[0][0]: # Output shape is 1x1x100x7
            conf = box[2]  #box[2] = result[0][0][2] is a probability value
            print("probability value : ",conf)
            print("box[0] : ",box[0]) #Object found or not
            print("box[1] : ",box[1]) #Object class
            print("xmin : ", box[3])
            print("ymin : ", box[4])
            print("xmax : ", box[5])
            print("ymax : ", box[6])

            #In below code, w and h are height and width of image respectively
            if conf >= 0.1:
                xmin = int(box[3] * w)  
                ymin = int(box[4] * h) 
                xmax = int(box[5] * w) 
                ymax = int(box[6] * h) 
                cv2.rectangle(imgToDisplay, (xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax), (0, 0, 255), 1)

             cv2.imshow('Object_detection',imgToDisplay)
```

Comment: what does it draw? can you show some samples?

Comment: It draws on people. And it draws bounding boxes.

Comment: I meant give a sample image where it fails.

Comment: Are you box coordinates coming as x,y or y,x?

Comment: I dont have any image to show you. It's just an image of a person without any boxes.
Box co-ordinates are x,y.